# calculate change in standard deviation when change in CI is available

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, meta-analysis

For my meta-analysis, I would like to know how to calculate change in standard deviation when a change in mean and change in confidence interval (between baseline and endpoint) is available

Comment: You know the confidence interval widths. You know the sample sizes. Work backwards from the confidence interval formula to get the standard deviation for each case.